# Convert and Cast Datetime not working

Tags: sql-server-2008, converters

I currently import a csv file into SQL via an SSIS package, on of the fields tIS date time. However the datetime field has GMT on the end (11/08/2013 15:47:53 GMT) so I do the below to remove it.

`CAST(REPLACE(Date, ' GMT', '') AS DATETIME) AS yDate`

This give me the following format `2013-11-08 15:47:53.000` - which should be YYYY-MM-DD

however I am having real problems converting the date into YYYY-DD-MM format, as SQL seems to think its the 11-Aug-2013 and not the 08-Nov-2013. I'm thinking its something to do with the replace code that removes the GMT but everything I try gives the same result?

has anyone come across anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the behaviour when using a space to separate the date and time is dependent upon which particular [`DATEFORMAT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) settings are currently in effect on your database connection.

A `T` separator (`2013-11-08T15:47:53.000`) should force an unambiguous parse:

```
CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Date, ' GMT', ''),' ','T') AS DATETIME) AS yDate
```

Another alternative would be to switch to using [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and specify an explicit style:

```
CONVERT(datetime,REPLACE(Date, ' GMT', ''),121) AS yDate
```

Comment: Massively frustrating! But i've managed to get it working using a staging table and forcing the dateformat with 'set dateformat YMD' and that appears to have worked! Thanks for above!